# 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, channel

I am running hyperledger-fabric network. I am following the fabric-sample's  balance-transfer example and the steps to run the network, Using the nodejs sdk .
I have Register and enroll new users in Organization in the network and that is successful, but when creating channel facing the error -
FORBIDDEN reason:implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

The response is as follows :-

```
POST request Create channel  ...

{"success":false,"message":"Channel 'Mychannel' failed to create status:FORBIDDEN reason:implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied"}
```

At the  logs :-

```
[2019-05-17 12:18:37.723] [DEBUG] Create-Channel -  result ::{"status":"FORBIDDEN","info":"implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied"}
[2019-05-17 12:18:37.723] [ERROR] Create-Channel - Failed to create the channel. status:FORBIDDEN reason:implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

Comment: I dont know if you changed something, but this policy is defined on configtx.yaml, try to check this. Or reset your local changes and try to run again.

Comment: I haven't  write any policy in  configtx.yaml , as I said earlier am following balance transfer example, the only difference is instead of 2 orgs , there are 5 orgs in my network.

Comment: That's the issue, you need to setup your orgs on configtx.yaml. In the begging of file there is a organization's section.

Comment: can you post your configtx.yaml file here. The issue could be from this configuration. I had this issue before, and I fixed it in that yaml file.

Comment: @RodolfoLeal is absolutely correct, adding orgs to an existing network is absolutely non-trivial. Even starting a network with multiple orgs requires all of them to be mentioned in the `configtx.yaml` file.